# Why does my javascript countdown timer occasionally over-run?

Tags: javascript, recursion, timer

As part of a web-based educational game, I have a countdown timer using the code that follows. Mostly, the timer stops at zero, but occasionally, it over-runs, and continues to count down from 59:59.

A couple of notes about the code:

1. countTime is a global variable set by a dropdown menu
2. stopCount is a gloabal variable set by a reset button
3. leadZero is an external function used for formatting

I understand that setTimeout is not very accurate, but I would have thought that the remTime > 0 condition would stop the recursion eventually, even if it missed the first time.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
function newCount() {
    var startTime=new Date();
    var min=startTime.getMinutes();
    var sec=startTime.getSeconds();
    var endTime=(min*60)+sec+countTime;
    stopCount=false;

    countDown();

    function countDown() {
        var today=new Date();
        var m=today.getMinutes();
        var s=today.getSeconds();
        var currTime=(m*60)+s;
        var remTime=endTime-currTime;
        var remMin = Math.floor(remTime/60);
        var remSec = remTime % 60;

        // add a zero in front of numbers<10
        remMin=leadZero(remMin);
        remSec=leadZero(remSec);

        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML=remMin+":"+remSec;

        if (remTime > 0 && stopCount==false) { 
            t=setTimeout(function(){countDown()},500);
        }
        else if (stopCount==false){document.getElementById("nextButton").innerHTML = "Finished";}
        else {} 
    }   
}
```

As requested, here is the code for the buttons and calling functions ...

Buttons:

```
<button onclick="newSyllable()" id="nextButton" style="font:60px 'Nunito', sans-serif;">Start</button>

<button onclick="resetScore()"><span style="font:20px 'Nunito', sans-serif;">Reset</span></button>
```

Functions:

```
function resetScore() {
    points=0
    stopCount=true;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + points
    document.getElementById("nextButton").innerHTML = "Start"
    document.getElementById("syllable").innerHTML = "&nbsp;"
    t=setTimeout(function(){setCountDown()},500);
}

    function newSyllable() {
    if (document.getElementById("nextButton").innerHTML == "Finished"){
    }
    else {
        if (document.getElementById("nextButton").innerHTML == "Start"){
            newCount();
        }

        document.getElementById("nextButton").innerHTML = "Next"


        switch (currentUnit) {
        case "1":
            unit1();
            break;
        case "2":
            unit2();
            break;
        case "3":
            unit3();
            break;
        case "4":
            unit4();
            break;
        case "5":
            unit5();
            break;
        case "6":
            unit6();
            break;
        }
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + points++
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the values you're using for `countTime` and `stopCount`? Or any information about what triggers the runover? I'm running your code and it's working fine.

Comment: The default value for countTime is 180 (3 mins); other values range from 1 min to 8 mins. stopCount is boolean; it's only set to true by the reset button. Unfortunately, I've only noticed the over-run some time after it happens. It only occurs very occasionally - about 3 times in 2 days now.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I see the problem...one second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I think the problem originates from the way you're calculating the remaining time by using two Date objects. A much simpler way to do this would be to just use your `countTime` variable as the starting time (in seconds), and then use a 1000 millisecond interval to perform the countdown. Try this code instead:

```
var stopCount = false;
var countTime = 10;

function newCount() {
    if(stopCount === false) {
        var counter=setInterval(countDown, 1000);
    }
    stopCount = true;

    function countDown() {
        countTime = countTime - 1;
        var remMin = Math.floor(countTime/60);
        var remSec = countTime % 60;
        // add a zero in front of numbers<10
        remMin=leadZero(remMin);
        remSec=leadZero(remSec);
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML=remMin+":"+remSec;

        if (countTime <= 0)
        {
            clearInterval(counter);
            document.getElementById("nextButton").innerHTML = "Finished";
            return;
        }
    }   
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5vxbe/8/

Comment: Thanks! That's a lot more reliable and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the code further, using the countTime = countTime-1 idea from @JL, but using my original setTimeout recursive function rather than setInterval and clearInterval.

I want the "reset" button to be able to stop and reset the timer before it's finished, and this code made that a bit simpler (I think).

Here's the final code:

```
function newCount() {
    stopCount=false;
    countDown();
    function countDown() {
        if (stopCount==false) {
            countTime=countTime-1
            var remMin = Math.floor(countTime/60);
            var remSec = countTime % 60;

            // add a zero in front of numbers<10
            remMin=leadZero(remMin);
            remSec=leadZero(remSec);
            document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML=remMin+":"+remSec;
            if (countTime > 0) { 
                t=setTimeout(function(){countDown()},1000);
            }
            else {document.getElementById("nextButton").innerHTML = "Finished";}
        }

    }   
}
```